# What is the default task memory?

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop map-reduce configuration provides the `mapred.task.limit.maxvmem` and `mapred.task.default.maxvmem.`

According to [the documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html#Memory+monitoring) both of these are values of type long that is anumber, in bytes, that represents the default/upper VMEM task-limit associated with a task. It appears that meaning of "long" in this context is 32bit and setting values higher than 2GB may lead to negative values being used as the limit.

I am running on 64 bit system and 2GB is much lower limit than I actually want to impose.

Is there any way around this limitation?

I am using hadoop version 0.20.1

Answer (score 1):

The long in this context refers to the amount of space required to store the setting not the actual amount of memory that can be addressed. So, you can use a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 inclusive. But, usually a long represents 64bits of data anyway.